# Como renderizar um componente jsf através do Bean?

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Preciso renderizar um componente jsf (Primefaces) através do Bean.
Tenho um selectOneMenu que muda o tipo de pessoa (física/jurídica) e preciso renderizar o campo "CPF", pois eu uso o mesmo campo para CPF/CNPJ e ao trocar o tipo, eu preciso mudar a máscara de entrada.

Como fazer?

Comment: Vou dar um chute aqui. `<p:inputMask mask="#{meuBean.padrao}" />`

Comment: Sim, isto é o básico, mas meu problema seria criar um componente no xhtml através do código java (bean).

Answer (score 2):

```html
<p:outputLabel class="required" value="Tipo de Pessoa:" for="tipo" />
<h:panelGroup>
  <p:selectOneRadio id="tipo" value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.tipo}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroClienteBean.tiposPessoas}" var="tipoPessoa" itemValue="#{tipoPessoa}" itemLabel="#{tipoPessoa.descricao}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="grupoLabel, grupoInput" process="@this" />
  </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="grupoLabel">
  <p:outputLabel class="required" value="CPF:" for="cpf" rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.tipo eq 'FISICA'}" />
  <p:outputLabel class="required" value="CNPJ:" for="cnpj" rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.tipo eq 'JURIDICA'}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup id="grupoInput">
  <p:inputMask mask="999.999.999-99" value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.documentoReceitaFederal}" id="cpf" rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.tipo eq 'FISICA'}" style="width: 50%" />
  <p:inputMask mask="99.999.999/9999-99" value="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.documentoReceitaFederal}" id="cnpj" rendered="#{cadastroClienteBean.cliente.tipo eq 'JURIDICA'}" style="width: 60%" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Post antigo mais pode ajudar outras pessoas... Eu uso desta forma usando ENUM...